# Mapping embeddings to labels in PyTorch/Huggingface

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, word-embedding

I am currently working on a project where I am using a pre-trained transformer model to generate embeddings for DNA sequences (some have a '1' label and some have a '0' label). I'm trying to map these embeddings back to their corresponding labels in my dataset, but I'm encountering an IndexError when attempting to do so. I think it has to do with the fact that I am batching since I'm running out of memory.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
from datasets import Dataset
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
import torch

# Load the tokenizer and model
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("InstaDeepAI/nucleotide-transformer-500m-human-ref")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("InstaDeepAI/nucleotide-transformer-500m-human-ref")

# Load the dataset
ds1 = Dataset.from_file('training.arrow') #this is already tokenized

# Convert tokenized sequences to tensor
inputs = torch.tensor(ds1['input_ids']).to(torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"))

# Reduce batch size
batch_size = 4

# Pass tokenized sequences through the model with reduced batch size
with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = model(input_ids=inputs[:batch_size], output_hidden_states=True)

# Extract embeddings
hidden_states = outputs.hidden_states
embeddings1 = hidden_states[-1]
```

Here is the information about the size of the output embeddings and the original dataset:

```
embeddings1.shape
torch.Size([4, 86, 1280])


ds1
Dataset({
    features: ['labels', 'input_ids', 'attention_mask'],
    num_rows: 22535512
})
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to map the labels back to the output embeddings, especially with the big discrepancy with the sizes. As you can see, I have 22million sequences, I would like a an embedding for each sequence.

My plan is to use these embeddings for downstream prediction using another model.
I have already split my data into train, test, and val, but does it make more sense to get the embeddings for a label1 dataset and label0 dataset and then combine and then split into train/test, so I don't have to worry about the mapping of the labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **.map** function in the dataset to append the embeddings. I suggest you run this on **GPU** instead of **CPU** since nos of rows is very high.

Please try running the code below.

```
import torch
from datasets import Dataset
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "CPU")

# Load the tokenizer and model
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("InstaDeepAI/nucleotide-transformer-500m-human-ref")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("InstaDeepAI/nucleotide-transformer-500m-human-ref", device_map = device)

# Load the dataset
ds = Dataset.from_file('training.arrow') #this is already tokenized

# Convert tokenized sequences to tensor
inputs = torch.tensor(ds['input_ids']).to(device)

# Reduce batch size
batch_size = 4

def get_embeddings(data):

    # Convert tokenized sequences to tensor
    input_ids =  torch.tensor(data['input_ids']).to(device)

    # Pass tokenized sequences through the model with reduced batch size
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(input_ids, output_hidden_states=True)
    
    hidden_states = outputs.hidden_states
    embeddings = hidden_states[-1]

    return {'embeddings' : embeddings.detach().cpu()}

# Extract embeddings
ds = ds.map(get_embeddings, batched=True, batch_size=batch_size)
ds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` function to compute embeddings and save them in the same dataset

```py
from transformers import DataCollatorWithPadding

collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer, padding=True, return_tensors='pt')

def embed(batch):
    inputs = collator({'input_ids' : batch['input_ids']})
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(**inputs, output_hidden_states=True)
        
    hidden_states = outputs.hidden_states
    embeddings = hidden_states[-1]
    return {'embeddings' : embeddings.detach().cpu()}

ds1 = ds1.map(embed, batched=True, batch_size=4)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! All of the seqs in my dataset are exactly the same length, so I don't need/want to pad the seqs. Bc of this, should I use DefaultDataCollator or just use DataCollatorWithPadding but with padding=False?

Comment: If all your sequences are the same length, you can swap the collator for just stacking the tensors together

Comment: Okay, can you please edit your code to show me what it would look like?